# No funciona .$("#contenido").css("display", "flex"); en Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

Tengo el siguiente código que muestra unos textos al hacer click en un botón.

Funciona bien en todos los navegadores **menos en Firefox 53.0.3 64 bits**, ¿alguna idea?

```
  $(document).ready(function(event) {
    $('#btn-servicios-1').click(mostrarServicios1);
    $('#cerrar-servicios-1').click(cerrarServicios1);
  });

  function cerrarServicios1() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#contenido-servicios-1").hide();
  }

  function mostrarServicios1() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#contenido-servicios-1").css("display", "flex");
  }
```

Acabo de probar:

```
$("#contenido-servicios-1").show();
$("#contenido-servicios-1").css("display", "flex");
```

Y tampoco funciona

He probado solo con

```
$("#contenido-servicios-1").show();
```

Y tampoco va, no es cosa de usar `show();` o `.css(display)`.

**PD: SOLUCIONADO**

```
function cerrarServicios1(event) {
    event.preventDefault(event);
    $("#contenido-servicios-1").hide();
  }

  function mostrarServicios1(event) {
    event.preventDefault(event);
    $("#contenido-servicios-1").css("display", "flex");
  }
```

Al final lo he solucionado añadiendo 'event' en las funciones. Gracias a todos por las molestias.

Comment: ¿has probado ha hacerle un ".show()" en mostrar servicios?

Comment: el problema es que el 'show()' creo que implica hacer un display: block; ¿no?. Yo necesito q sea display: flex;

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Firefox?

Comment: 53.0.3 64bits (lo acabo de instalar ademas) @fedorqui

Comment: ok, era por sber si te funcionaba

Comment: Nada, tampoco funciona con show() @Carmen

Comment: En algunos foros aconsejan actualizar la versión de jquery, no sé si puede serte de ayuda. ¿Te carga correctamente el jquery?

Comment: He probado usando jquery-3.2.1.js y tampoco @Carmen

Comment: Pues me quedé sin ideas, salvo quizás probar a reinstalar Firefox por si algo falló en la instalación, porque no tiene mucho sentido que no funcione

Comment: Gracias de todos modos @Carmen no te preocupes. De la instalacion no creo que sea porque en otro ordenador tampoco funciona.

Comment: Cuando inspecciones el elemento, mantiene display:flex, o se está sobre escribiendo?

Comment: Has probado con display: -webkit-flex;?

Comment: También intenta con: display: -webkit-flex;

Comment: @MarkLenders te sugiero agregar una respuesta, no una edición a tu pregunta con la solución.

Answer (score 1):

Justo te estaba escribiendo una solución parecida cuando veo que lo has solucionado. Aquí te dejo el código que probé yo:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-servicios-1').click(mostrarServicios1);
   $('#cerrar-servicios-1').click(cerrarServicios1);
 });

 function cerrarServicios1() {
   $("#contenido-servicios-1").hide();
   return false;
 }

function mostrarServicios1() {
  $("#contenido-servicios-1").css("display", "flex");
  return false;
}
```

`return false` también sirve para parar la propagación. Espero que te sea útil :)

Comment: Vaya gracias @Sergio Clebal ! Tomo nota.